# AWS Cognito and Identity Server missing Claims in C# application

Tags: c#, amazon-cognito, identityserver4, claims

Using AWS Cognito with Identity server I am unable to obtain the full claims in either the id_token or access_token (from my client app).

One of the attributes we need to obtain is the email, this is enabled in the app pool client:

[image: AWS Cognito:]

When I query the tokens in my client app, the email claim is not present.

[image: Getting the tokens]

Even stranger, when I run the below code on the Identity Server application I can see all the claims that I need:

[image: IDS App Server code]

I am unsure why my client application does not have access to the same claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I implemented ProfileService and added the claims there.

One thing I didn't understand at first was that it is the client app that fires the GetProfileDataAsync method, and not the Identity Server itself.

See: https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2020/04/identityserver4-adding-additional.html

Answer (score 0):

In the client application, some claims are renamed, and some claims are removed, so what you would expect to be present in the User object is not there.

You have things like claims transformation and claims mapping that you might need to set depending on what your actual needs are.

For example, on AddOpenIDConnect, there is an option named options.MapInboundClaims that you can set to false.

You might also need to point out the name of the role and name claim as well using:

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
    RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
};
```

You can also need to manually point out which claims you want to be mapped into the User object, using:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("gender", "gender");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("birthdate", "birthdate");
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)